# Excel conditional formatting to highlight row different colours depending on content of cells within two ranges

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet with columns A–AR populated. If cell range H, J and L, and cell range U, Z, AE and AJ each contain only one populated cell, the whole row should be highlighted green. If the two ranges contain fewer than one populated cell in each range, then the row should be highlighted orange. If neither of these conditions are met, e.g. all the cells are populated, no formatting should be applied.

Any help with this greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried? So if one of H,J,L has text and one of U,Z,AE,AJ has text then make green. If one of the ranges has all empty then make red. If any other combination  then dont do anything?

Comment: @BenRhys-Lewis: Yes, that's right! My knowledge of conditional formatting is so far pretty limited. I know how to format the row based on one cell being blank or not, but don't know how to add these multiple variables.

Comment: Ok I added an answer saying what worked for me just now in my test.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNTBLANK()` to check if cell is blank or `LEN()` to see if length is 0. So highlight the row then once in the new rule dialogue, choose fill colour and in the formula add something like:

```
=AND(COUNTBLANK(H1), COUNTBLANK(J1), COUNTBLANK(L1))
```

This would make the row red if all of these three cells are empty.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. For some reason, however I enter the range that the formula should apply to ($1:$1, or A1:AR1), only cell A1 and cells AN1 onwards are highlighted. The highlighting doesn't appear in cells B1–AM1. I don't have any other conditional formatting on the sheet, so can't figure this out.

Comment: If you click 'manage rule' in conditional dropdown it shows 'Applies to' field. This shows all the cells that are using that formula to format.